# All but last child element of css menu is moved one pixel left

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, menu, parent-child

I'm tearing my hair out here.
I have horizontal dropdown menu on a site I am building.  The menu is made up of an unordered list, with the dropdown part made up of hidden child elements that pop up when you roll over the parents.
In Firefox everything appears to be fine, but, in Chrome and Safari, while the last child element in each menu is acting as expected, all other child elements are shunted left by one pixel.  So, in the example below, Child A3, Child B4, and Child C2 are aligned perfectly with their respective parents, while the rest are not.
Can someone please shed some light on what is going wrong here?
Code and screenshots below...

[How it should look...](http://www.helluva.co.uk/images/menu-right.jpg)

[How it actually looks...](http://www.helluva.co.uk/images/menu-wrong.jpg)

I have included the entire nav block of the CSS just in case I have missed something outside of the actual parent/child part.

HTML

```
<nav>
    <div id="menu" class="menustrip">
        <ul>
            <li class="page_item">
                <a href="http://www.mysite.com/services">Parent A</a>
                <ul class='children'>
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://mysite.com/">Child A1</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://mysite.com/">Child A2</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://mysite.com/">Child A3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/products">Parent B</a>
                <ul class='children'>
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://mysite.com/">Child B1</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://mysite.com/">Child B2</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://mysite.com/">Child B3</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://mysite.com/">Child B4</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="page_item"><a href="http://www.mysite.com/products">Parent C</a>
                <ul class='children'>
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://mysite.com/">Child C1</a></li>
                    <li class="page_item"><a href="http://mysite.com/">Child C2</a></li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
```

CSS

```
#menu, #main-nav{
    width: 950px;
    margin:  0 30px 0 0;
    padding-right: 30px;
    border-bottom-style: solid;
    border-bottom-width: 8px;
    border-bottom-color:  #78B2E2;
    text-align: right;  
}

ul#main-nav{
    list-style: none;
    padding-top: 10px;
    margin-right:30px;
}

.page_item, .navlink{
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #243488;
    height: 34px;
    width: 110px;
    margin-left: 1px;
    text-align: center;
}

.page_item a, .navlink a{
    padding-top: 4px;
    display: block;
    height: 34px;
    width: 110px;
}

.page_item:hover, .navlink:hover{
    background-color: #78B2E2;  
}

.page_item:active, .navlink:active{
    background-color: #78B2E2;  
}

    /* Hide Sub Menus by default */  
       #menu ul li ul.children {  
        display:none; 
        z-index:100; 
    }  

       /* Display Sub Menus on rollover of parent */  
    #menu ul li:hover ul.children {  
        display:block;  
        position:absolute;  
        top:205px; 
        margin: 0 0 0 -11px; /*pull child menus in line with parent */  
        width: 132px;
        list-style: none;  
    }  

       /* Style sub menu items not to float like parent items */  
    #menu ul li ul.children li {  
        float:none;  
        width:110px;  
        height: 34px;
        background-color:#243488;           
        border-top: 3px solid #ffffff; 
        font-size: 11px;
    }

        #menu ul li ul.children li:hover {   
        background-color:#78B2E3;
        color:#243488;   
    }

    /* Sub Menu link color  */
    #menu ul li ul.children li a:hover {  
        color:#243488;  
    }

    #menu ul li ul.children li a {  
        color:#ffffff;  
    }
```

Comment: Do you have a jsfiddle demo?

Comment: Or can you give us a link to the actual page if it is published?

Comment: I must have done something wrong in jsfiddle because it is all over the place on there
http://jsfiddle.net/Maffu/nDdyf/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what causes it exactly, but it has to do with the fact that the list items in `<ul class="children">` are inline-blocks and the ul itself is centered.

So you have two solutions: either align the ul to the left instead of centering it

```
.children {text-align:left;}
```

or, make its list items blocks instead of inline blocks.

```
.children > li {display:block;}
```

Either of those adjustments will get rid of the display anomaly. In both cases, you will also have to increase the left margin, but I'm sure that won't be a problem.

Comment: Thanks Mr Lister - that worked.  I might get through the day with some hair left now :)

Answer (score 0):

Changing `.children .page_item` to `display:block` rather than `display:inline-block` seemed to fix it in my Chrome. This also required a bit more margin-left to re-align things.

```
.children .page_item {
 display:block;
margin-left:10px;
}
```